# Adding a smooth fitted line (loess) to a bar graph

Tags: bar-chart, loess

I am trying to add a loess curve to a bar plot.
After loading the ggplots2 package, I first create the bar plot:

```
test<-read.csv("tseries.csv", header = TRUE)  
barplot(test$tn90p, beside = TRUE,ylim =c(-6,6))  
lo<-loess(tn10p~year, test)   pred<-predict(lo, se = TRUE)
a<-order(test$year)
```

So far so good, until I try to add the smoothed curve:

```
lines(test$year[a], pred$fit[a], col = "red", lwd = 2)
```

When I do that, no error message, the prompt comes back, but no line is added.
What am I missing?
Thanks for your help.

***Note: when I dput(test), I have this***:

```
structure(list(year = 1951:1980, tn90p = c(3.126667391, 4.091391006, 
3.11420404, 5.117428018, 2.281128013, 2.654342884, 4.189742845, 
-0.448909654, 1.634574903, -1.324893538, -0.675205784, -1.876889174, 
-2.689793785, 0.364812684, -1.859920287, -1.736813462, -1.527857975, 
-3.214404324, -4.189742845, 0.448909654, -1.634574903, 1.324893538, 
0.675205784, 1.876889174, -0.436873606, -4.45620369, -1.254283753, 
-3.380614556, -0.753270038, 0.560061439)), .Names = c("year", 
"tn90p"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -30L))
```

Comment: I  realize that there is a typo in my code. There is no tn10p. I have only tn90p.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I could make it work:

> test<-read.csv("tseries.csv", header = TRUE)
>   attach(test)
>   p = barplot(test$tn90p, names.arg=test$year, beside = TRUE, ylim =c(-6,6))
>   lo<-loess(tn90p~year)
>   lines(p, predict(lo), col="red", lwd=3)
>   abline (h=0, lwd=1)